# Error mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given

Tags: php, mysql

tengo el siguiente problema que me gustaría resolver,

Estoy haciendo una consulta con Mysql para validar en la base de datos si existe un correo electrónico que voy a ingresar y no me deje registar el correo ya que se encuentra registrado en la base de datos

```
 $consulta_correo="select count(*) as 'cantidad' from turista where CORRTURI=".$correo;
 $resultado_correo=mysqli_query($mysqli,$consulta_correo);
 $cantidad_correo=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_correo)['cantidad'];
 if ($cantidad_correo>0) {
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">mostrarMensajeError(\"El Correo electronico que intenta registrar ya existe en la base de datos\");</script>";
    $validacion=false;
 }
```

Al ejecutar el código me genera el siguiente error:

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in el nombre del proyecto y la linea del codigo $cantidad_correo

¿Cual puede ser el problema?, Saludos y muchas gracias,

Comment: Haz un `vardump` del resultado de tu query. La [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) dice que `mysqli_query` retorna *false* en caso de error. Por lo que probablemente tu query no se esté ejecutando correctamente y el valor al que quieres acceder no exista en la variable que usas como parámetro  en la función `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable es que tu consulta no esté regresando ningún registro, más bien un error, y por tal motivo la variable `$resultado_correo` es en ese momento un valor `false`. Creo que te está dando false porque en tu consulta el correo electrónico debe ir entre comillas, prueba con:

```
$consulta_correo="select count(*) as 'cantidad' from turista where CORRTURI='".$correo."'";
```

Comment: Gracias esa es la solución, agradezco buena noche

Comment: Que bien, agradecería que la marcaras como respuesta aceptada.